# Excel converting all numeric values in Worksheets to Doubles

Tags: excel, vba

I'm testing the output of a VBA program in Excel, and to my surprise it seems like all numeric outputs on the worksheet are converted to vartype 5 (Double). I've reproduced this in different worksheets and workbooks.

Part of the vba code assigns a long variable to the value of a cell

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").value = longVar
```

Although longVar is declared as a Long, varType(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").value) yields 5 which is the vbDouble type.

Why does this happen? Is there a workaround so variables are not converted to doubles?

Comment: Looking to understand this better. Is this a known bug in Excel? Is this something in my environment? Is this expected behavior? And if so, what's the rationale, and is there a workaround so variables are not converted to doubles?

Comment: Why does this happen? Is there a workaround so variables are not converted to doubles?

Comment: I don't think you can return a `vbLong` from a cell on a worksheet - how would Excel store a long in a cell? It has to be stored a double, no?

Comment: I think what you are looking for, (although I'm guessing) is a way to understand the underlying types of data in a cell. I think maybe what you are looking for is:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlrangevaluedatatype `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value(12)`. This will return the XML of the field, which will contain the underlying type Excel thinks the cell is.

Comment: If you have to check the type of a value you’re setting via code, then check the code variable type itself. If you have to check the type of a value already in a cell, you want to use some numeric check like “CInt(cell.Value) = cell.Value” and handle the approximation

Comment: It's because for Excel all values are double. You can test it with `MsgBox TypeName(ActiveCell.Value)` - and you will always get `Double`.